# Request time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

There are 3 KVM virtual machines. Operating system Windows Server 2019. MySQL settings and version are the same. The same request is being made.The execution time is very surprising.

1. 1 CPU 2.30GHz  RAM - 1G   request time  0.187 sec.
2. 2 CPU 2.25GHz  RAM - 4G   request time  3.844 sec.
3. 2 CPU 2.80GHz  RAM - 4G   request time 24.140 sec.

Runs fastest on the dumbest machine.The difference is 10 times between the second and third machine with almost identical characteristics. Is there an explanation for this?

```
SELECT g.id, g.name,
       IFNULL( 
       (SELECT SUM(t.kol) 
        FROM prh_z z, prh_tl t 
        WHERE (z.id = t.id_z)AND(t.id_goods = g.id)AND(z.docdate < '2023-01-01')AND((z.id_stores = -1)OR(-1 <= 0))),0) AS kol_ost_plus, 
       IFNULL( 
       (SELECT SUM(t.kol) 
        FROM nkl_z z, nkl_tl t 
        WHERE (z.id = t.id_z)AND(t.id_goods = g.id)AND(z.docdate < '2023-01-01')AND((z.id_stores = -1)OR(-1 <= 0))),0) AS kol_ost_minus, 
            
       IFNULL( 
       (SELECT SUM(t.kol) 
        FROM vnk_tl t, vnk_z z  
        WHERE (z.id = t.id_z)AND(t.id_goods = g.id)AND(z.docdate < '2023-01-01')AND((z.id_stores_p = -1)OR(-1 <= 0))),0) AS kol_ost_plus_v,
       IFNULL( 
       (SELECT SUM(t.kol) 
        FROM vnk_tl t, vnk_z z  
        WHERE (z.id = t.id_z)AND(t.id_goods = g.id)AND(z.docdate < '2023-01-01')AND((z.id_stores_i = -1)OR(-1 <= 0))),0) AS kol_ost_minus_v,

       IFNULL( 
       (SELECT SUM(t.kol) 
        FROM prh_z z, prh_tl t 
        WHERE (z.id = t.id_z)AND(t.id_goods = g.id)AND(z.docdate >= '2023-01-01')AND(z.docdate < '2023-05-01')AND((z.id_stores = -1)OR(-1 <= 0))),0) AS kol_plus, 
       IFNULL( 
       (SELECT SUM(t.kol) 
        FROM nkl_z z, nkl_tl t 
        WHERE (z.id = t.id_z)AND(t.id_goods = g.id)AND(z.docdate >= '2023-01-01')AND(z.docdate < '2023-05-01')AND((z.id_stores = -1)OR(-1 <= 0))),0) AS kol_minus, 
    
       IFNULL( 
       (SELECT SUM(t.kol) 
        FROM vnk_tl t, vnk_z z  
        WHERE (z.id = t.id_z)AND(t.id_goods = g.id)AND(z.docdate >= '2023-01-01')AND(z.docdate < '2023-05-01')AND((z.id_stores_p = -1)OR(-1 <= 0))),0) AS kol_plus_v,
       IFNULL( 
       (SELECT SUM(t.kol) 
        FROM vnk_tl t, vnk_z z  
        WHERE (z.id = t.id_z)AND(t.id_goods = g.id)AND(z.docdate >= '2023-01-01')AND(z.docdate < '2023-05-01')AND((z.id_stores_i = -1)OR(-1 <= 0))),0) AS kol_minus_v
FROM goods g 
WHERE g.upname LIKE '%%' 
ORDER BY g.upname ASC
```

There are no questions about the request itself. All necessary indexes are present.

Comment: You should stop using the archaic comma separated table list in favour of more _"modern"_ and explicit joins with the join criteria in the `ON` clause. If using MySQL8 you will _probably_ see a significant benefit from moving the 8 correlated subqueries to 3 [lateral derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html). To understand the differences between your three VMs, you could start by running the query with EXPLAIN on each instance, then updating the statistics for all tables involved, and then running with EXPLAIN again.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data and query plan are identical on all three machines.

Comment: Are those average query times or one offs?

Comment: This is a stable and repeating time with every request.

Comment: What is your physical location?  What is the physical location of 1. 2. 3. ? Are the 3 servers yours or hosted by a public hosting organization?  From each machine, please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query); please.  For Analysis.

Comment: Virtual machines are not clones. Rent VDS from different service providers. I only have access to the virtual machine, which below I don't know.

Comment: Can you provide the URL's of the 3 Rented VDS servers?

Comment: Using an IO benchmarking tool (like [DiskSpd](https://github.com/microsoft/diskspd)) might help you quantify the differences in storage performance between the three VMs. You should also test the performance of your query with the VMs configured appropriately. Assuming your dataset does not currently fit in memory, you should retest with more RAM allocated to [InnoDB's buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html).

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded. I figured out the reason, how to fix it is another question. It turned out that in all cases different storages are used. On the first machine - HDD. By the second machine - NAS. On the third machine - SSD.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please - from each srvr.. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.